# Sum of each individual index value for any two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

JavaScript program to compute the sum of each individual index value for any two arrays

Example:

```
array1 = [16,0,2,3,4];
array2 = [3,5,6,7,8,13];
```

Expected Output :

```
[19, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider asking a question, and including a sample of what you've tried so far; you're much more likely to get an answer. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint : use a loop to go through the array and store the result in another variable.

Comment: [`R.zipWith(R.add)`](http://ramda.github.io/ramdocs/docs/)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this code:

```
var array1 = [16,0,2,3,4],
    array2 = [3,5,6,7,8,13],
    l = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length);
```

You can try a `for` loop:

```
var result = Array(l);
for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) result[i] = (array1[i] || 0) + (array2[i] || 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated .

Added function `_len` to test arrays `a` , `b` for greatest `length` property `i` , and least `length` property `j` , between the two argument arrays.

Arrays `a` , `b` , can be input in any order to `_len` . The input array `i` , having greatest `length` property between the two input arrays, calls [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) .

Return array `array3` , by adding each member of `i` to each member of to `j` , at the corresponding `k` index ; return members of `i` if no corresponding `k` index members at `j`

```
var array1 = [16,0,2,3,4]
     , array2 = [3,5,6,7,8,13]
     , len = array1.length
     , array3 = (function _len(a, b) {
                var i = a.length > b.length ? a : b
                , j = i === a ? b : a;
                return i.map(function(v, k) {
                    return v + j[k] || v  
                });
              }(array1, array2))
```

```js
var array1 = [16,0,2,3,4]
     , array2 = [3,5,6,7,8,13]
     , len = array1.length
     , array3 = (function _len(a, b) {
                var i = a.length > b.length ? a : b
                , j = i === a ? b : a;
                return i.map(function(v, k) {
                    return v + j[k] || v  
                });
              }(array1, array2))
console.log(array3);
document.write(array3)
```

Comment: If `array2` is not necessarily the largest array, this approach could ignore the last numbers of `array1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure JavaScript too.

```js
    var array1 = [16,0,2,3,1];
    var array2 = [3,5,6,7,8,13];
    var array3 = [];

    if (array1.length >= array2.length)
    {
        array3 = array1.map(function(num, i, array) {
          return num + (array2[i] || 0);
        });
    }else{
        array3 = array2.map(function(num, i, array) {
          return num + (array1[i] || 0);
        });
    }


    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "array3: " + array3.toString();
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Since `array1` is shorter, `array3` won't have the last number of `array2`.